# SignalR Redis message bus

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

I'm using RedisMessageBus as a backplane. From this article https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr I know, that the server delivers messages to clients from its local cache.

But what will happen if the server was offline and missed some messages from the message bus?

Comment: That scenario is beyond the scope of the given article....can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I have two servers, Redis message bus and two clients connected to these servers (C1 > S1, C2 > S2). For some time server 2 goes offline. Client 1 continues to send messages to server 1 and to publish them to message bus. Meanwhile server 2 is not subscribed for these messages. Server 2 goes online and client 2 reconnects to this server. Will he get missed messages?

Comment: Are S1 and S2 behind a load balancer?..is this a web farm scenario?

Comment: They are behind a load balancer.

Comment: Then if S2 goes down, all the new request from client 2 goes to S1, the responses get stored in the redis cache, so there is no loose of information...you can test this scenario and shut down one of your servers on purpose, to see what happens